# QTP Object Properties frequently changed in the application

Tags: qtp

I am automating an appilcation in QTP. I am using descriptive programming approch for identifying the object in the application. My problem is for every iteration or release the object properties values getting changed in the application. Do we have any ways to automatically update the object propertie values in the automation suite. if so what is that?. if not what is the best approch to update the objects in the suite with minimum time? Kindly suggest me.
Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: Parameterization perhaps ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a description is that it's consistent, this may be a bit of a challenge if the application is very dynamic (for more details see [an explanation on how object identification works in QTP](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/Technical-How-QTP-identifies-Objects/ba-p/2409612)).

Tools that QTP gives you in order to combat this problem are:

- Regular expressions
- Parametrisation

You should try and find which properties in your application are most dependable and use those. One option is to ask your R&D to add some dependable properties if none currently exist. You may also try using Visual Relations Identifiers (VRI) as explained [here](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2012/02/03/qtp-visual-relation-identifier/) and in [this YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6qJIYBJ7KI). If you are using UFT (version 11.5 and later) you can also use the appearance of the control via [Insight for *image based object identification*](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855).